# Sum $\sum \frac{1}{(4k-3)(4k-2)(4k-1)(4k)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

I am stuck on this problem for quite a while now, and I don't seem any closer to the solution. So, here it is:
$S = 1/4! + 4!/8! + 8!/12! + 12!/16! + ......$ 
I crossed out the factorials first, and it could be easily represented by the general term, 
$T = \frac{1}{(4n-3)(4n-2)(4n-1)(4n)}$
It looked like it could be expressed as the difference of two expressions which could come useful to find the sum, what we call the 'diagonal cancellation',
$T = \frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{(4n-1)(4n-2)(4n-3)} - \frac{1}{4n(4n-1)(4n-2)})$
but unfortunately it doesn't work. I even unintentionally split it further into subtractions of two more expressions for both terms and so on, which finally leads to a harmonic series, which is certainly not expressible in "closed-form'.
Please help by suggesting a simple math solution, this is merely a class notes illustration and I am not an advanced maths student.

Comment: [Wolfram alpha knows the answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+i%3D0+to+inf+%284i%29%21%2F%284%28i%2B1%29%29%21). It is $1/24 (\ln(64) - \pi)$

Comment: This is not an easy expression in general. Basically, unless the poles of the expression are integer distances from each other, you shouldn't expect anything nice. If you want to work with these types of series, here is a paper that has some of the more interesting details. http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~tijdeman/tijsho3.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

\begin{align*}
& \frac{1}{(4n-3)(4n-2)(4n-1)(4n)} \\
&= \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{(4n-1)(4n-2)(4n-3)} - \frac{1}{4n(4n-1)(4n-2)}\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{3\cdot 2}\left( \frac{1}{(4n-2)(4n-3)} - \frac{2}{(4n-1)(4n-2)} + \frac{1}{4n(4n-1)}\right) \\ 
& = \frac{1}{3\cdot 2\cdot 1}\left( \frac{1}{4n-3} - \frac{3}{4n-2} + \frac{3}{4n-1} - \frac{1}{4n}\right) \\ 
\end{align*}

So the sum is \begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( \frac{1}{4n-3} - \frac{3}{4n-2} + \frac{3}{4n-1} - \frac{1}{4n}\right) =\\
& =\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( \int_0^1 x^{4n-4} dx -3 \int_0^1 x^{4n-3} dx+ 3\int_0^1 x^{4n-2} dx - \int_0^1 x^{4n-1} dx\right) = \\
& = \frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( \int_0^1 x^{4n-4} - 3 x^{4n-3} +3x^{4n-2}  -  x^{4n-1} dx\right) = \\
& \stackrel{*}{=} \frac{1}{6} \int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(x^{4n-4} - 3 x^{4n-3} +3x^{4n-2}  -  x^{4n-1}\right) dx = \\
& = \frac{1}{6} \int_0^1 \frac{1 - 3x + 3x^2 - x^3}{1-x^4} dx = \\ 
& = \frac{1}{6} \int_0^1 \frac{(1-x)^2}{(1+x)(1+x^2)} dx = \cdots = \frac{1}{24}(6\ln2 - \pi)\\ 
\end{align*}

Here the step $\stackrel{*}{=}$ should be justified; the integrand is of the form $x^{4n-4}(1-x)^3$ and this is nonnegative on $[0,1]$ so Fubini-Tonelli is appliable.